# ¿Es correcto insertar la misma respuesta en diferentes preguntas?

Tags: soporte

En los últimos días hay una pregunta persistente relacionada con [Google y la desactivación de aplicaciones menos seguras](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es). La mayoría de las librerías que requerían la desactivación de aplicación menos seguras para enviar correos con `gmail`, dejaron de funcionar y muchos usuarios buscan respuestas relacionadas a ello en su lenguaje específico de programación.

Por ejemplo:

- [Gmail no Permite PhpMailer ultima actualizacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/541209/186586) - Esta pregunta está buscando solucionarlo con PhPMailer.
- [Desactivación de aplicaciones menos seguras de google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/539336/186586) - Esta pregunta estaba buscando una solución para el problema en unos scanners que usaban el correo de `gmail`.
- [Envio automático de correos con python y smtp (actualización junio 2022)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/539447/186586) - Esta pregunta estaba buscando una solución con `smtplib` en `python`.
- [Nodemailer ya no envia correos, google desactivo la opcion de "Acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/538073/186586) - Esta otra pregunta busca la solución pero con `nodemailer` en `nodejs`.

Entre muchas otras que terminan cerradas porque los usuarios no saben cómo afrontar la pregunta, ya que no es un error propio en su código.

Todas esas preguntas conllevan a la misma respuesta, de ahí que surge mi pregunta: **¿Es correcto agregar la misma respuesta en todas esas preguntas?**

Hice una [respuesta general](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/539336/186586) e hice también una versión modificada [para python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/539447/186586). Iba a agregar respuestas en las otras dos, pero siento que no está bien duplicar la respuesta.  Intenté reportar las preguntas cómo duplicada de [la más general que tengo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/539336/186586) y que ya lleva más de 800 vistas, pero no puedo, porque quien la preguntó fue uno de esos usuarios fugaces que desaparece sin dejar rastro y no marcó mi respuesta como aceptada. ¿Cómo se procede en este caso?

---

### Edición

Por alguna razón que no sabía, pasado unos días puedo hacer el reporte de duplicado. Acabo de comprobarlo y ahora sí me lo acepta. Antes me decía que no se podía porque la pregunta no tenía una respuesta aceptada. Que me deje hacerlo responde parcialmente a mi pregunta, porque creo que lo mejor es marcar el duplicado. Pero de cualquier manera me gustaría tener una respuesta de la comunidad para el caso en el que no se pueda hacer el reporte. ¿Sería correcto duplicar la respuesta?

Comment: Una pregunta no puede ser marcada como duplicada de otra si esta última no tiene ninguna respuesta con puntaje positivo o aceptada

Comment: Puedes crear una pregunta que resuma el problema, y luego dar y aceptar tu propia respuesta. Así tendrás una respuesta aceptada contra la cual marcar las otras como duplicadas.

Comment: @CandidMoe buen punto

Comment: Opino igual que Candid, lo mejor que podes hacer, si sabes la respuesta, es escribir una pregunta canonica, y dejar tu respuesta ahi, aceptarla, y que todas las preguntas ya hechas y futuras sean duplicado de esas. Ahora, si la respuesta es arreglar el codigo de cada lenguaje, entonces deberias hacer una pregunta respuesta por lenguaje...

Comment: Gracias a todos. @gbianchi En general lo único que había que cambiar en este caso es la contraseña. El código no cambia. De cualquier forma, más que la pregunta en específico de `gmail` quería quedarme con una manera de proceder para futuros casos. Con suerte, si alguien en el futuro se encuentra en la misma situación que yo, encuentra esta pregunta en meta. Dado que ya puedo marcar la respuesta más general como duplicada, no vale la pena hacer yo una pregunta, pero lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima.

Comment: Es que si vale la pena. si tu respuesta no fue aceptada, estaria bueno que este en una pregunta que tenga seguimiento, y sea una respuesta que se pueda aceptar. A mi gusto (y esto es solo mio) me gusta mas cuando linkeamos a una respuesta aceptada...

Comment: ah lo que si no es correcto, es duplicar respuestas. Si la respuesta es duplicada, la pregunta es duplicada. El sistema nos alerta en esos casos...

Comment: tengo una pregunta que encaja perfectamente con tu respuesta pero no la tengo asi... https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/541690/46896